# Average matrices in a cell array within a structure Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, data-structures, concatenation, cell-array

In Matlab I have a structure `AVG` of size `1 x 6` which has one field `averageNEST` that is a cell array also of size `1 x 6`.

Each `averageNEST` contains matrices of varying sizes (in one dimension), so for example

`AVG(1).averageNEST{1,1}` is of size `281 x 3 x 19` and

`AVG(1).averageNEST{1,2}` is of size `231 x 3 x 19`

The 2nd and 3rd dimensions of the matrices are always 3 and 19, it is only the first dimension that can change.

I want to average over all the matrices contained within `AVG(1).averageNEST` and obtain one matrix of size `X x 3 x 19` where X is the size of the smallest matrix in `AVG(1).averageNEST`.

Then I want to do this for all 6 `averageNEST` in `AVG` - so have a separate averaged matrix for `AVG(1), AVG(2) ... AVG(6)`.

I have tried multiple things including trying to concatenate matrices using the following code:

```
 for i=1:6
    min_epoch = epoch + 1;
         for ii=1:19
            averageNEST(:,:,ii) = [AVG(i).averageNEST(1:min_epoch,:,ii)];
         end
 end
```

and then average this but it doesn't work and now I'm really confused about what I'm doing!

Can anyone help?

Comment: I do not completely understand how you would like to average. You say over all matrices in `AVG(1).averageNEST` but they are of variable size, so averaging is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand what you want to do. If you want to keep only the elements up to the size of the the smallest matrix and then average those matrices you can do the following:

```
averageNEST = cell(size(AVG)); 
for iAVG = 1:numel(AVG)
    nests = AVG(iAVG).averageNEST;
    minsize = min(cellfun(@(x) size(x,1), nests));    
    reducednests = cellfun(@(y) y(1:minsize, :, :), nests, 'UniformOutput', false);
    averageNEST{iAVG} = sum(cat(4, reducednests{:}), 4) / numel(nests);
end
```